# Find the average of a field of multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table **ratings**:

```
part     rating     numReviews
----     ------     ----------
A1       100        5
A1       50         2
A2       90         4
A3       100        4
```

I need to find the rating average for each part. In the above example A2 is 90 and A3 is 100 as they are single lines. Easy.

However, part A1 is multiple lines so i need to do **rating * numReviews** for each line then divide by the **total numReviews**

Is this possible? This is what I'm trying (microsoft SQL):

```
select part, 
cast((AVG((rating * numReviews) / SUM(numReviews))) as decimal(5,2)) as rating_average
from tableName group by part order by part
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

Answer (score 2):

If the rating column store the value of individual ratings (meaning you have 4 ratings with value 100 with a total of 400 for A3 and you want to know the average value of ratings (calculated as `total per group / (rating value * rating count)` ) and the output should be:

```
part AverageRating
---- ---------------------------------------
A1   85.71428571428571428571428571
A2   90.00000000000000000000000000
A3   100.00000000000000000000000000
```

Then this query will do it:

```
select 
    part, 
    sum(rating * numreviews)/sum(cast(numreviews as decimal(5,2))) as AverageRating
from tableName 
group by part
```

If on the other hand the rating column stores an aggregate of ratings (meaning the value of 100 for A3 should be interpreted as 4*25) and you want the average rating per group with this output:

```
part rating_average
---- ---------------------------------------
A1   21.4285714285714285714
A2   22.5000000000000000000
A3   25.0000000000000000000
```

Then this:

```
with ratings as (select 
    part, 
    sum(rating) r, 
    sum(numreviews) as c
from TableName
group by part
)
select part, avg(r/cast(c as decimal)) AS rating_average
from ratings 
group by part
```

I think it's the former you are looking for, not the latter.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select part, Sum(rating) as ratings,Sum(numReviews) as TotalReviews,
        (Sum(rating) /sum(numReview )) as rating_average
From tableName
Group By part
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `SUM`:

```
SELECT part, 
    CAST(SUM(rating * numReviews) / SUM(numReviews) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) as rating_average
FROM tableName
GROUP BY part
ORDER BY part
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it step by step for clarity sake

```
SELECT Level1.*,(Level1.ratings/Level1.TotalReviews) as rating_average
FROM
  (
     Select part, Sum(rating) as ratings,Sum(numReviews) as TotalReviews
     From tableName
      GroupBy part
   ) as Level1
```